# How to assign additional properties to template data?

Tags: meteor

In Meteor document:

> In addition to the properties and functions described below, you can assign additional properties of your choice to the object. Use the onCreated and onDestroyed methods to add callbacks performing initialization or clean-up on the object.

So how can I do that? I have made a sample, but it does not work.

```
Template.Test.onCreated = function () {
  this.xx = 11;
  }
}

Template.Test.events({
  'click #submit': function (e, template) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(template.data);
  }
});
```

neither would `this` or `template.data` print `xx`.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call it passing an event handler as an argument to onCreated

```
Template.Test.onCreated(function(){
      this.xx = 11;
})
```

And when you want to get the value from events

```
Template.Test.events({
'click #submit': function (e, template) {
   console.log(template.xx);
  }
})
```

Comment: Not template.data.xx? What is template.data ?

Comment: Dont mess with template.data :D it's a meteor internal object for template instance